# are "put on your top / bottoms" more common than "put on your Tshirt / shirt / tank top / pants / shorts ..." in English in casual daily situations?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

I am not a native speaker. I found that it is easier for me to say this to my daughter when we go out "**Sweetie, please put on your top / bottoms**" than "**Sweetie, please put on your Tshirt / shirt / tank top / pants / shorts...**" because I don't have to think what specific kinds of tops and bottoms she should put on & it is up to her to choose what to put on.

are "**put on your top / bottoms**" more common than "**put on your Tshirt / shirt / tank top / pants / shorts ...**" in English in **casual daily situations**?

[In Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=put%20on%20your%20top%2Cput%20on%20your%20shirt%2Cput%20on%20your%20tank%20top&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cput%20on%20your%20top%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cput%20on%20your%20shirt%3B%2Cc0), "**put on your shirt**" is much more common than "**put on your top**"

Answer (score 1):

Though both are common, I think ***may*** depend on the *gender.* While shirts are common with men, females may go with *top* as they have more varieties. Seldom we hear that *He was wearing a nice top.* More common is *He was wearing a nice shirt.*

Comment: In British English _top_ is commonly used of female garments, for the reason Maulik gives. I don't think _bottoms_ is so widely used, probably because of the other connotations of the word. Clothing catalogues do refer to _pyjama bottoms_ and _tracksuit bottoms_, but it wouldn't be used of trousers in general.